# The Operator '<' can't be unconditionally

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a problem with my code if someone can help me fix the bug i appreciate

heres the code

```
 new TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        validator: (input) => input?.length < 3
                                ? "Email id Should be valid"
                                : null,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Email Address",
```

> It is show error "The operator '<' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Comment: `input?.length` means it will return `null` if `input` is `null`. So what you potential have is `null < 3` which is not allowed since `null` does not implement the `<` operator.

Comment: the input isn't a null

Comment: No, but `input` is a nullable type and can therefore be `null`. So the compiler will tell you that what you are doing is potential a problem at runtime.

Comment: can you show me how to implement it

Comment: Yes, I have posted an answer with two examples showing how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are completely sure that `input` can never be `null` in this scenario, you can force the compiler to assume that `input` is not a nullable type:

```
 new TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        validator: (input) => input!.length < 3
                                ? "Email id Should be valid"
                                : null,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Email Address",
```

Alternative, you can do this so the `null` scenario is handled as `false` since we can promote `input` to non-nullable by testing for `null` before using it:

```
 new TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        validator: (input) => (input != null && input.length < 3)
                                ? "Email id Should be valid"
                                : null,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Email Address",
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
 new TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        validator: (input) => (input?length < 3 ?? false)
                                ? "Email id Should be valid"
                                : null,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Email Address",
```

this will work. change true, false as per your condition

Comment: This does not solve the problem where `input?.length < 3` is invalid since you can potentially compare against `null`.

Comment: its showing error message "the left operand can't be null, so the right operan is never executed.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
  hintText: 'Email Address',
  labelText: 'Email',
  ),
  validator: (value) {
     if (value.isEmpty) {
       return "Email can'\t be empty";
     } else if (value.length < 3) {
       return "Email length shoud be 3 charecter";
     }
     return null;
    },
),
```

Comment: That does not solve anything since `value` can be null according to: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormFieldValidator.html . So you are not allowed to call `.isEmpty` on a value which can potentially be `null`.